# Define a variable after insert?

Tags: apex

I have an object Inscripci_n tha has a master-detail relationship with Contacts and Servicio__c.

This is part of my class. My problem is with the line "  ServicioId =  objInscripci.Servicio__c;
" After inserting the Inscripci_n, I need to bring the Servicio Id to use it in the code after the insert.

Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks!!

```
  public class FormTestController{
     public Contact contact {get;set;}
     public String ServicioId {get;set;}
     public String ContactId {get;set;}      
     public Servicio__c Servicio {get;set;}
     public Inscripci_n__c objInscripci {get;set;}

     public FormTestController(){

         ContactId  = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
         contact=[Select Otra_nacionalidad__c,Name,id,FirstName,LastName,Documento_de_identidad2__c,G_nero__c,Fecha_de_Nacimiento__c,
         Nacionalidad__c,Direcci_n__c,C_digo_Postal__c,Ciudad__c,Estado_o_provincia__c,Pa_s__c,MobilePhone
         ,Email,Phone,Facebook__c,OtherPhone,De_qui_n_es_el_tel_fono_de_contacto__c, Barrio_Urbanizaci_n_Zona__c  from Contact where id=:ContactId];

         objInscripci  = new Inscripci_n__c();

     }

       public PageReference Finish(){
     try{
          system.debug('--- here is contact ='+ contact );
          system.debug('--- here is Servicio='+ Servicio);
          update  contact;

          system.debug('here is exception Servicio='+Servicio);            
             objInscripci.Joven__c = contact.Id;
             //objInscripci.Servicio__c = Servicio.Id;   
             insert objInscripci; 
          return new PageReference('/'+ContactId  );

          }

          catch(exception ex){
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,ex.getMessage() ));
         return null;
       }


    }

    public PageReference ContinuetoSurvey(){
      try{
         /* if(objInscripci.Fecha_de_ingreso__c != date.Today()){
              ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Please use today date in Fecha de ingreso'));
              return null;
          }*/
           system.debug('--- here is contact ='+ contact );
          system.debug('--- here is Servicio='+ Servicio);
          update  contact;

          system.debug('here is exception Servicio='+Servicio);            
             objInscripci.Joven__c = contact.Id;
             //objInscripci.Servicio__c = Servicio.Id;   
             insert objInscripci;
             ServicioId =  objInscripci.Servicio__c;

         Servicio=[Select id,Tipo_de_Servicio__c,Alianza__c  from Servicio__c where id=:ServicioId];
         objInscripci.Servicio__c = ServicioId;

          if(Servicio.Tipo_de_Servicio__c=='Formación'){
              return new PageReference('/apex/Form2?Id='+contact.Id+'&ServicioId='+ServicioId+'&FormType=2');
          }
          else{
              return new PageReference('/apex/Form3?Id='+contact.Id+'&ServicioId='+ServicioId+'&FormType=3');
          }
          return null;
         }
      catch(exception ex){
              ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,ex.getMessage() ));
             return null;
         }
     }    
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to set the `Inscripci_n__c.Servicio__c` field if you don't do so explicitly? Is there a trigger that sets this value? If so, you will need to use a SOQL query to retrieve the new value.

Comment: Sorry! New a this.. I thought that after inserting an object "insert objInscripci; I could just ask for any field from that new object (ServicioId =  objInscripci.Servicio__c;)   I will find the way of creating the SOQL there. Thanks!

Comment: Since you are inserting the record, I'm wondering what you expect to have set that value. Without a trigger or worflow field update it is likely to still be null when you use a SOQL query to retrieve it.

Comment: This class is used for a visualforce. Users have to add information about the student and the Inscription (Inscripci_n), including a lookup field with the Service (Servicio) where they will be assigned. 
Once they click Continue to survey, I need the Id of the service they select in the to the Inscripci_n they created,  in the returnURL. Does this make sense?

Comment: @Elena Servicio is not getting populated right? can we see the visualforce `apex:form`  that you're using to set it?

Comment: It is to long to past it here. The form ask for the service as a lookup field. The service is already created.         <apex:inputField label="Seleccionar servicio" value="{!objInscripci.Servicio__c}"/>


Thank you!!!!